# Iterating through a Window of a String without collect

Tags: string, rust

I need to iterate through and compare a window of unknown length of a string. My current implementation works, however I've done performance tests against it, and it is very inefficient. The method needs to be guaranteed to be safe against Unicode.

```
fn foo(line: &str, patt: &str) {
    for window in line.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().windows(patt.len()) {
        let mut bar = String::new();
        for ch in window {
            bar.push(*ch);
        }
        // perform various comparison checks
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, your performance tests have isolated the performance issue to which specific part of the included code?

Comment: On my machine, calling the method (fixed to compile and with a basic equality check in place of the comment) takes 4.7 seconds where `line` is 100MiB of "a" followed by a "b" and `match` is "ab" (this time includes the time to build that string). What kind of time / performance are you looking for?

Comment: @Shepmaster fixed. And the actual non MWE is https://github.com/Aaronepower/tokei/blob/master/src/lib/utils/fs.rs#L18 which I've tested through flamegraph profiling running against the huge source trees(e.g. Linux).

Comment: @Shepmaster now it is. It is also very hard to test from mobile.

Comment: We are more than happy to wait for posters to get the question in order before posting it the first time (in fact, we will never even know). Maybe that means using a different computer. If you find yourself trying to use the playground on mobile a lot, [the alternate Playground](http://play.integer32.com/) has a "simple editor" mode that is much easier to use with virtual keyboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An improvement on Shepmaster's final solution, which significantly lowers overhead (by a factor of ~1.5), is

```
fn foo(line: &str, pattern: &str) -> bool {
    let pattern_len = pattern.chars().count();

    let starts   = line.char_indices().map(|(i, _)| i);
    let mut ends = line.char_indices().map(|(i, _)| i);

    // Itertools::dropping
    if pattern_len != 0 { ends.nth(pattern_len - 1); }

    for (start, end) in starts.zip(ends.chain(Some(line.len()))) {
        let bar = &line[start..end];
        if bar == pattern { return true }
    }

    false
}
```

That said, your code from the Github page is a little odd. For instance, you try to deal with different length open and close tags with a wordier version of

```
let length = cmp::max(comment.len(), comment_end.len());
```

but your check

```
if window.contains(comment)
```

could then trigger multiple times!

Much better would be to just iterate over shrinking slices. In the mini example this would be

```
fn foo(line: &str, pattern: &str) -> bool {
    let mut chars = line.chars();
    loop {
        let bar = chars.as_str();
        if bar.starts_with(pattern) { return true }
        if chars.next().is_none() { break }
    }

    false
}
```

(Note that this once again ends up again improving performance by another factor of ~1.5.)

and in a larger example this would be something like

```
let mut is_in_comments = 0u64;

let start = match line.find(comment) {
    Some(start) => start,
    None => return false,
};

let end = match line.rfind(comment_end) {
    Some(end) => end,
    None => return true,
};

let mut chars = line[start..end + comment_end.len()].chars();
loop {
    let window = chars.as_str();

    if window.starts_with(comment) {
        if nested {
            is_in_comments += 1;
        } else {
            is_in_comments = 1;
        }
    } else if window.starts_with(comment_end) {
        is_in_comments = is_in_comments.saturating_sub(1);
    }

    if chars.next().is_none() { break }
}
```

Note that this still counts overlaps, so `/*/` might count as an opening `/*` immediately followed by a closing `*/`.

Comment: @Shepmaster True, I've clarified the wording.

Comment: Do you think the performance boost is because you don't need to allocate the `Vec` at all? How does your solution avoid the ugly corner case that `char_indices` doesn't return an index for "the character after the end" that mine needed an extra block for?

Comment: @Veedrac The larger example code actually [fails in this test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=84e865af19aafea8910f8458183dc976&version=stable&backtrace=0) as it loses the first character in the `next()`.

Comment: @Aaronepower Ah, good point. I never actually ran the later, so I'm just glad it kind'a worked at all. They should be fixed now.

Comment: @Shepmaster Probably - the `Vec` is ~8x the size of the input, after all, and your inner loop has two `unwrap`s that my version doesn't. I avoid the end case by using `ends.chain(Some(line.len()))`. (Sadly iterating over a `chain` doesn't compile well, so this comes at a very minor performance cost relative to copying the body.) The main difference between that and the version with `starts_with` is that the later only parses the unicode once.

Comment: I feel that `let ends = line.char_indices().map(|(i, _)| i).skip(pattern_len);` is a more explicit way to do that bit.

Comment: @trentcl `skip` has per-iteration overhead, since it wraps an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

> The method needs to be guaranteed to be safe against Unicode.

`pattern.len()` returns the number of **bytes** that the string requires, so it's already possible that your code is doing the wrong thing. I might suggest you check out tools like [QuickCheck](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck) to produce arbitrary strings that include Unicode.

Here's my test harness:

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let mut haystack: String = iter::repeat('a').take(1024*1024*100).collect();
    haystack.push('b');

    println!("{}", haystack.len());
}
```

And I'm compiling and timing via `cargo build --release && time ./target/release/x`. Creating the string by itself takes **0.274s**.

I used this version of your original code just to have some kind of comparison:

```
fn foo(line: &str, pattern: &str) -> bool {
    for window in line.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().windows(pattern.len()) {
        let mut bar = String::new();
        for ch in window {
            bar.push(*ch);
        }

        if bar == pattern { return true }
    }

    false
}
```

This takes 4.565s, or **4.291s** for just `foo`.

The first thing I see is that there is a lot of allocation happening on the inner loop. The code creates, allocates, and destroys the `String` for each iteration. Let's reuse the `String` allocation:

```
fn foo_mem(line: &str, pattern: &str) -> bool {
    let mut bar = String::new();

    for window in line.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().windows(pattern.len()) {
        bar.clear();
        bar.extend(window.iter().cloned());

        if bar == pattern { return true }
    }

    false
}
```

This takes 2.155s or **1.881s** for just `foo_mem`.

Continuing on, another extraneous allocation is the one for the `String` *at all*. We already have bytes that look like the right thing, so let's reuse them:

```
fn foo_no_string(line: &str, pattern: &str) -> bool {
    let indices: Vec<_> = line.char_indices().map(|(i, _c)| i).collect();
    let l = pattern.chars().count();

    for window in indices.windows(l + 1) {
        let first_idx = *window.first().unwrap();
        let last_idx = *window.last().unwrap();

        let bar = &line[first_idx..last_idx];

        if bar == pattern { return true }
    }

    // Do the last pair
    {
        let last_idx = indices[indices.len() - l];

        let bar = &line[last_idx..];
        if bar == pattern { return true }
    }

    false
}
```

This code is ugly and unidiomatic. I'm pretty sure some thinking (that I'm currently too lazy to do) would make it look a lot better.

This takes 1.409s or **1.135s** for just `foo_mem`.

As this is **~25%** of the original time, [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) suggests this is a reasonable stopping point.